# nginx + cgi (c++ programs)

Tags: linux, arch-linux, nginx, fastcgi

I am stuck setting my nginx to work with custom cgi programs (using xmlrpc-c library).
I am trying with fcgiwrap/spawn-fcgi like this:

```
$ spawn-fcgi -f /usr/bin/fcgiwrap -s /tmp/fcgi.sock
```

Important section of nginx.conf file would be

```
location /cgi-bin/test {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html/cgi-bin/test/;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;

        #fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:8000;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/tmp/fcgi.sock;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /usr/share/nginx/html/cgi-bin/test$fastcgi_script_name;

    }
```

I've tried both soceket files and ipv4/portnumber combinations but i got error:

```
2013/08/22 18:52:55 [notice] 1645#0: signal process started
2013/08/22 18:52:57 [crit] 1653#0: *1 connect() to unix:/tmp/fcgi.sock failed (13:             Permission denied) 
while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost,request: "POST /cgi-bin/test/listaccounta HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/tmp/fcgi.sock:", host: "localhost", referrer: "http://localhost/some_page.php"
```

I also get 502 Bad Gateway sometimes if I mess around with options. I've tried every combination I could google (includes modifying /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf file)
(note there are separate sections in nginx.conf for php cgi and for my test programs, php works fine)
I am stuck and don't know how to configure it, am I missing something out?

this part especially:

in nginx.conf
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /usr/share/nginx/html/cgi-bin/test/$fastcgi_script_name; #desn't work, reports error below
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/share/nginx/html/cgi-bin/test/my_prog; #it works

```
Cannot get script name, are DOCUMENT_ROOT and SCRIPT_NAME (or SCRIPT_FILENAME) set and is the script executable?
```

i have more than one program, how to set executable not to be fixed (like my_prog above)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like nginx doesn't have permission to read/write the fastcgi socket:

```
2013/08/22 18:52:57 [crit] 1653#0: *1 connect() to unix:/tmp/fcgi.sock failed (13:             Permission denied)
```

You should make sure that the user account used to launch nginx can access the socket file created by fcgi. Are they both launched as the same user?

Comment: I suspected this as well, tried both chmod a+rwx /tmp/fcgi.sock as well as running those services as root, same error (permission denied)